# Probability estimation

Tags: probability

The plant produced $100$ lots of parts, and from each one randomly checked $5$ parts for standardization. As a result, $0$ parts turned out to be standard in $55$ lots, $1$ in $22$ lots, $2$ in $10$ lots, $3$ in $5$ lots, $4$ in $4$ lots, $5$ in $4$ lots. Assuming that the probability of recognizing the standard is the same for all details and that the tests were independent, determine this probability.

I tried to calculate theoretical probabilities using Bernoulli's formulas using the parameter $p$, and then tried to find the most appropriate value for $p$. I have used the least squares method, but I am not sure if this is correct. It turned out $p=0.09843519240$, that is, approximately $0.1$.

It is not entirely clear, however, why the probability of a standard detail is so small, but this is obtained from the given condition, not the solution.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Jellyfish "determine this probability." As I said, I'm not sure if my method is correct and if I calculated it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of $500$ parts inspected, $93$ turned out to be defective.  So I would estimate the probability that the probability that a part is defective as
$$\frac{93}{500} = 0.186$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to determine the probability is using maximum likelihood estimation. The likelihood function is

$$\begin{pmatrix}100\\
55,22,10,5,4,4\end{pmatrix}P(X=0)^{55}P(X=1)^{22}P(X=2)^{10}P(X=3)^5P(X=4)^4P(X=5)^4\\
=\frac{100!}{55!22!10!5!4!4!}[(1-p)^5]^{55}\cdot
           [5p(1-p)^4]^{22}\cdot[{5 \choose 2}p^2(1-p)^3]^{10}\cdot [{5 \choose 3}p^3(1-p)^2)^5\cdot[5p^4(1-p)]^4[p^5]^4$$

You can use numerical methods to find the global maximum or plotting it it looks like $\hat p$ is a little less than 0.2.

[image]